# How to generate a sequence number for particular accounts present in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a situation like if account is not present in other table (table2) then the below query will generate a seq number 1 else it should generate a incremental sequence number for every same type of accounts.

Query :

```
select 
account_ID,
(case when (B.seq) is null then 1 else B.seq+1 end) as col1,
desc as desc
from table1
left join 
(select id, max(seq_no) seq from table2 group by id) B
on table1.id=B.id
```

---

:table2:

```
ID    account_id     seq_no
1      100            1
1      100            2
2      101            1
```

Expected result need from the table1 query:----------

```
account_id    col1     desc
102             1       abc
102             2       xyz
102             3       apc
100             3       pqr
100             4       mn
101             2       home
101             3       hall
```

Please help me out to get this result in sql server query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your table1 data look like? What is your current result?

Comment: perhaps you can try rewording your narrative of what you are trying to do and make it more clear what tables are your input and desired result I have read your question a few times now and don't get what you are asking.

Comment: Table1 contains account_id and description(desc). I have to generate a sequence for those similar types of account. current result is  like :
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
account_id      col1(seq)    desc
102                  1                 abc
102                  1                 xyz
102                  1                 apc
100                  3                 pqr
100                  3                 mn
101                  2                 home
101                  2                 hall

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I think that what you're asking for is a sequence number for each account_id that will start one value after the maximum value in Table2, but will keep increasing regardless of how many entries are in Table1.

The query below uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to create a sequence.  The `PARTITION BY` makes it "reset" itself once per account_id, and the `ORDER BY` tells it which rows come first in the sequence (note that you didn't indicate how these should be sorted in your original post, and thus I chose the description field randomly).

I used your same `LEFT JOIN` condition to identify the maximum sequence available for that account_id, and added that to the `ROW_NUMBER()` value, if it exists already.  The `ISNULL()` is intended to handle any account_id values that don't yet have a sequence.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (account_id INT, descr VARCHAR(4))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID INT, account_id INT, seq_no INT)

INSERT INTO @Table1 (account_id,descr)
    SELECT 102, 'abc' UNION 
    SELECT 102, 'xyz' UNION 
    SELECT 102, 'apc' UNION 
    SELECT 100, 'pqr' UNION 
    SELECT 100, 'mn' UNION 
    SELECT 101, 'home' UNION 
    SELECT 101, 'hall'


INSERT INTO @Table2 (account_id,seq_no)
    SELECT 100, 1 UNION 
    SELECT 100, 2 UNION 
    SELECT 101, 1

SELECT
    a.account_id
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.account_id ORDER BY descr) + ISNULL(b.seq,0) AS col1
   ,a.descr AS descr
FROM @Table1 a
    LEFT JOIN
     (
         SELECT
             [@Table2].account_id
            ,MAX([@Table2].seq_no) seq
         FROM @Table2
         GROUP BY [@Table2].account_id
     ) B
        ON a.account_id = B.account_id
```

Note that you'll have to adapt the code to your own table/column names, and potentially refine the `ORDER BY` within the partitioned function: I've given a general example.